# Sending SMS via Amazon SNS service using REST

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I am trying to develop a follow up on this AWS request:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

It works when you do it "as-is", but I'm trying to send a SMS from that script, and keep on getting "signature mismatch" response (HTTP 403):

```
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>a58398ba-74c1-5308-abbe-cfe97a28fc30</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Now, what I've changed in the (default) Python script is just this part (of course, didn't put my phone number publicly):

```
method = 'GET'
service = 'sns'
host = 'sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-west-2'
endpoint = 'https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
request_parameters = 'Action=Publish&Message=TestSenderID&Version=2010-03-31&PhoneNumber=00123123123'
```

And, of course, replaced the access and secret keys.

However, when I do the same request via Postman, for example, it works. Which leaves me in doubt on what's possibly wrong with this request, using nothing but default Python script.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
The "request_parameters" string has an order to it, where Version should go at the end.

```
Action=Publish&Message=Test&PhoneNumber=00123123123&Version=2010-03-31
```

Hope this helps in the future if more people get stuck on this issue.